# Kong JWT invalid signature

Tags: jwt, kong

I am using APIs in my web application to fetch data and display.I need the APIs to be authenticated/authorized before accessing the database, so I am using Kong API Gateway to authenticate/authorize the requests(APIs).I am trying to create jwt plugin in Kong but getting invalid signature while validating the request with the JWT .

How to fix Invalid signature error? I am using Kong 0.10.3 in Linux server(I am not using docker or AWS).

Code:
Below are the steps which I followed:

```
Step 1.Created Kong API Route:
curl -X POST http://localhost:8001/apis/ \
   --data "name=Abc" \
   --data "uris=/API" \
   --data "upstream_url=http://*.*.*.*:1212" \
   --data "strip_uri=false"

Step 2.Created plugin
curl -X POST http://localhost:8001/apis/ABC/plugins \
    --data "name=jwt" 

Step 3.Created Consumer
curl -X POST http://localhost:8001/consumers \
    --data "username=xyz" 

Step 4.Created JWT credentials
curl -X POST http://localhost:8001/consumers/xyz/jwt -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Step 5.Send a request with the JWT(Using the JWT debugger at https://jwt.io)

curl http://localhost:8000/API/ABC?user=1 \
    -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiI4OTg2MTgwZTQ0ZGQ0ODBmOGU5YzBlODQ3OTQyNDk1YSJ9.sIquZPSmkU8t9RVC8PSBqB8hbs2Th0IIOgphp2iWn2E'

{"message":"Invalid signature"}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know your problem is solved till now. but I entered my solution for anyone who is encountered this issue. You should put the key created in the JWT section of the consumer in the "iss" key as the value to create a token. I created an image to describe it Visually. Note that the "iss" can be configurable.

[image: jwt token]

Answer (score 1):

Have you added `iss` to your JWT token payload, as described on https://getkong.org/plugins/jwt/?

> Secondly, the claims must contain the secret's key in the configured claim (from config.key_claim_name). That claim is iss (issuer field) by default. Set its value to our previously created credential's key. The claims may contain other values.

```
{ 
  "iss": "a36c3049b36249a3c9f8891cb127243c"
}
```

Comment: I too get the same error even when I am having iss (which is the key of the consumer). My jwt is eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJjc1pqT1RMaGgxTU9pSVJuNlV1NlptVzR6T2tWb3pCUiIsInN1YiI6Im1haWx0bzptaWtlQGV4YW1wbGUuY29tIiwibmJmIjoxNTMwMTc3NTMwLCJleHAiOjE1MzAxODExMzAsImlhdCI6MTUzMDE3NzUzMCwianRpIjoiaWQxMjM0NTYiLCJ0eXAiOiJodHRwczovL2V4YW1wbGUuY29tL3JlZ2lzdGVyIn0.K3YlVqpn-O2E86WCj6NOSUT0ZB4wmeHAuK1Ahu-Bkjo . This is my secret used to sign the jwt rjrLDRC980cbjcGD8plbsIa2xzwpwsJZ . I checked validity of the signature using http://kjur.github.io/jsjws/tool_jwt.html.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, I was generating JSON Web Tokens in a java application with the same secret as the kong consumer and putting the "iss" in the claims, but Kong still gave me the invalid signature message.

After some tests on https://jwt.io/ to generate tokens I noticed that the java application was generating tokens with the base64 encoded secret and kong was waiting for the secret not to be encoded, so added config.secret_is_base64 = true to jwt plugin solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilites.
1) Token is invalid i.e. not generated correctly.
2) Token is valid, buttoken not verified using correct verification keys.

Hint for point 1
Also, I see header empty when I decrypted the token in https://jwt.io/

Hint for point 2
You need to provide additional information like JWT algorithm, token verification key while creating JWT credentials. step 4.